# PyQt5 Unable to Center Align Text in Qlabel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using pyqt for the first time and I am trying to figure out how to get the text "example.py" in my Qlabel to align vertically. In this code I have set the Qlabel to a fixed height of 35, but the text is not sitting center between the top of the window and the top of the splitter below it.

If I set the fixed height of the Qlabel to 20, that gets a little closer to things looking vertically aligned (but not totally) but also introduces the problem of some of the bottom of the test "example.py" getting cut off.

Maybe it has something to do with some margin or something above the splitter section... Makes me think that it could be the case and that's why the text is getting cut off at the bottom. In either case I am not sure how to address the issue.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QSplitter, QStyleFactory,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #self.showFullScreen()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        topbar = QLabel("example.py", self)
        topbar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
        topbar.setIndent(20)
        topbar.setFixedHeight(35)
        layout.addWidget(topbar)

        v_left = QFrame(self)
        v_left.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        v_middle = QFrame(self)
        v_middle.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        v_right = QFrame(self)
        v_right.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.setHandleWidth(0)
        splitter.addWidget(v_left)
        splitter.addWidget(v_middle)
        splitter.addWidget(v_right)

        layout.addWidget(splitter)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('PiePy')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I found the solution to my issue while I was working on setting up transparency. I added the line `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoSystemBackground, True)` to my code and that made it clear in the application that there is indeed a space between the Qlabel and the splitter below it.

The solution was a simple one I just added `layout.setSpacing(0)` to the code and that took care of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a QVBoxLayout where it will obey its default behavior, try putting your topbar inside a QHBoxLayout and adding this layout to your main layout(QVBoxLayout). Once you have this configuration add a stretch in each side of your topbar inside the QHBoxLayout to make it goes to the middle.

You would have something like that, from your code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QFrame, QSplitter, QStyleFactory,
    QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        #self.showFullScreen()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout_title = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)

        topbar = QLabel("example.py", self)
        topbar.setAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
        topbar.setIndent(20)
        topbar.setFixedHeight(35)
        layout_title.addStretch(-1)
        layout_title.addWidget(topbar)
        layout_title.addStretch(-1)
        layout.addLayout(layout_title)
        v_left = QFrame(self)
        v_left.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        v_middle = QFrame(self)
        v_middle.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        v_right = QFrame(self)
        v_right.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)

        splitter = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal)
        splitter.setHandleWidth(0)
        splitter.addWidget(v_left)
        splitter.addWidget(v_middle)
        splitter.addWidget(v_right)

        layout.addWidget(splitter)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 1000, 800)
        self.setWindowTitle('PiePy')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The logic is that you have something like that:

```
#      [---------------------------------]    <-main_layout  (QVBoxLayout)
# item1 [---stretch----topbar----stretch]    <-layout_title (QHBoxLayout)
# item2 [------------QSplitter----------]
#      [---------------------------------]    <-main_layout  (QVBoxLayout)
```

Comment: Thank you. I did discover a solution in the meantime also. I edited my OP.